# Playing a sound file through a menu item

Tags: android, menu, fragment, android-mediaplayer, menuitem

I am trying to play a sound file through a menu item which exists in a fragment.

Here is the full code of my fragment,

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,false);

    ImageButton popupCTelevision = (ImageButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.chineseTelevision);
    ImageButton popupCBathe = (ImageButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.chineseBathe);
    ImageButton popupCSick = (ImageButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.chineseSick);

    popupCTelevision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), v);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_chinese_television);
            popupMenu.show();

        }
    });

    popupCBathe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), v);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_chinese_bathe);
            popupMenu.show();

        }
    });

    popupCSick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), v);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_chinese_sick);
            popupMenu.show();

        }
    });


    return rootview;
}


public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.c_bathe:
            final MediaPlayer CSick = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.c_bathe);
            MenuItem playCSick = (MenuItem) getView().findViewById(R.id.c_sick);
            CSick.start();

            playCSick.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    CSick.start();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        default:
            return false;


    }
}
```

}

I think the issue is that the method `onMenuItemClick` is not used at all. How do I implement this method for the code?

How do I do it similarly to pressing a button to play the sound file?

```
final MediaPlayer englishSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.english_bath);
    Button playEnglishBath = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play_english);
    playEnglishBath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            englishSoundMP.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The code should work, despite you maybe want to add an OnComplete Listener to the MediaPlayer so you can release the resources.

Comment: Oh the code works, but it does not play the recording upon clicking the selected menu item. Do you mind expanding on that? I don't quite follow. Because if I simply use a button to play the soundfile, I don't have to use an OnCompleteListener for the MediaPlayer

Comment: Have you tried logging if you get inside the  case `R.id.c_bathe`

Comment: Why you don't just start playing it ? You are getting an other view and putting an item click listener on that instead of playing the sound....  just call CSick.start() after you initialized the player.

Comment: @OgnianGloushkov, you are right, I tried logging and it doesn't go into the case at all, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `R.id.c_bathe` is it the correct view id you're clicked?